# Debugger has attached to process: What next?

Tags: .net-4.5, visual-studio-debugging

I am trying to debug a process that is already running. I am using Visual Studio .Net 4.5, and I have attached the debugger to an installed application on the same machine as the debugger. I've followed the instruction's on [Microsoft's page about it](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s68z0b3.aspx#Attach%20to%20a%20running%20process%20on%20the%20local%20machine), and the debugger appears to have successfully attached itself.

However, I don't know what I should be seeing after that. The normal debugging tools appear, but I don't see any code or any way to add break points/pause the application. The text at the top of the window says "Solution1 (Running)..." but I don't see an option to view the solution. Where the code normally would appear, and where there's normally a window to select and view files, it's just empty and grey.

Every solution I've seen on this topic just stops here, as if the next step should be obvious. So, what am I supposed to see here?

Comment: This seems like an appropriate question for a screenshot.

Comment: I'm not familiar with remote debugging in Visual Studio. If its anything like IntelliJ, you'll need to open navigate to the source files yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the normal scenario would be that you open the project with the source code of the attached program, attach to the program, and only then you can set breakpoints. If the code version is different than the one that's running, you will not be able to set breakpoints.

Comment: Thank you for the timely response! If I've understood correctly, it sounds like the normal procedure is to already have the application's source code open in the debugger before I attach it to the process. Is that correct?